# LLVM AND i64 needed result 1

Tags: llvm

Why in LLVM and don't return 1 as a result after use and?

This is my example what i use

define i64 @main() {
%1 = and i64 5, 5
ret i64 %1
}

I need receive result as a 1

Comment: I created it with ICmp Eq and it works